# Simple String Split

Tags: java, android, parsing, csv

Clearly, I am losing my mind. I have the following string:

`Tuesday|6:00 pm|Sub 10:00|Name`

I want to split that into 4 tokens using the "|" as a delimiter. Easy, right?

```
 String myString = "Tuesday|6:00 pm|Sub 10:00|Name";
 System.err.println(myString);
 String[] tokens = myString.split("|");     
 for (int i=0; i<4; i++) System.err.println(tokens[i]);
```

And here is my output:
`Tuesday|6:00 pm|Sub 10:00|Name`
`T`
`u`
`e`

What am I missing? (this is going to be one of those 'Doh!' moments, I predict.) Thank you!

Comment: This happens all the time. Whoever was the "genius" at SUN who came up with the idea that `split` and `replaceAll` should take a `regex`, he was wrong.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Having such a method is fine, but the naming is very misleading. Let's forget it and use Guava's [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression as its argument. The pipe character `|` is a meta-character in regular expressions which denotes OR. It needs to be escaped

```
String[] tokens = myString.split("\\|");
```

otherwise the `String` is split into its individual characters

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. I'll accept as soon as SO lets me.